# Redis replica can not perform HGETALL or Lua script

Tags: c#, redis, lua

I am using C# and Redis (local docker image and azure reids) and want to perform "HGETALL" and lua scripts on the replica instance, but that does not work. As this commands are read only, I expected that should work.

I get following exceptions:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: 'No connection is active/available to service this operation: HGETALL industry_pdi_eu.demo.BB000019, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: AT-PF1W0XL6(SE.Redis-v2.6.48.48654), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=12,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=32765,Min=12,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=10,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=32), v: 2.6.48.48654'
```

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: 'No connection is active/available to service this operation: EVALSHA, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: AT-PF1W0XL6(SE.Redis-v2.6.48.48654), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=12,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=32765,Min=12,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=10,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=31), v: 2.6.48.48654'
```

Are this commands not supported by redis replicas? If yes, why?

Comment: I found out that I need to configure the replica as second endpoint in the redis configuration. But I do not find any second endpoint at my azure redis instance.


```
var connectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379,abortConnect=False", (opt) =>
{
    opt.EndPoints.Add("localhost", 6380);
});
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with the deployment type (sentinel / cluster) you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
I am using a master/replica constellation. I though that I just need to enter the master address, but i also need to specify the replica address.

```
"Configuration": "localhost:6379,localhost:6380,abortConnect=False"
```